# Set default Style for FrameworkElement is not applied to derived class

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am a beginner in XAML. I create a new default style in a `ResourceDictionary`.

```
<Style TargetType="FrameworkElement" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type FrameworkElement}}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
</Style>
```

Then I import it to `UserControl.Resources`.

```
<ResourceDictionary>
   <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/PathToStyle.xaml"/>
   </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

What I expect is that it will be applied to all `FrameworkElement`s used in that `UserControl`, but it is not.

What infomation am I missing here?

Comment: Did you add a FrameworkElement into UserControl? Or some inheriting class object, that has it's own default Style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because TargetType is specific.

A style which you do not give a x:Key to automatically is given a key which is equivalent to it's type.

Hence your style:

```
 <Style TargetType="FrameworkElement"
```

Actually has an x:Key given to it which is

```
 <Style x:Key="{x:Type FrameworkElement}"
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.style.targettype?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_Windows_Style_TargetType

A piece of ui which is "looking" for a style looks for a matching key to it's type using that x:Key. It does not search up it's inheritance chain as well.

EDIT:

You can prove this:

In a new wpf app, add a frameworkelement to you mainwindow and a style targets frameworkelement.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="FrameworkElement">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="10"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <local:TestSubClass/>
</Grid>
```

and

```
public class TestSubClass : FrameworkElement
```

Spin it up and take a look at the live visual tree > Properties.
The frameworkelement fills the grid and has an actualheight matching the grid's height.
No style is set on it.
Hence this is the situation where no style is set and inheritance is not working as claimed in another post.

Change that to a regular frameworkelement:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="FrameworkElement">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="10"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <FrameworkElement/>
</Grid>
```

Spin it up with an f5 and take a look at the live visual tree.

There is a style in the properties.

Actualheight is 10.

Comment: @AnyCan you give me a link about your sentence [ It does not search up its inheritance chain as well.]

Comment: @dellos I edited my post, adding how to prove this is the case.  If this was a datatemplate, the inheritance chain on Datatype  would work. Maybe this is what confused the other poster.

Answer (score 0):

> What I'm expecting is it will apply to all FrameworkElement used in That UserControl

By all `FrameworkElement`s you probably mean all `FrameworkElements` including its derivatives. Applying the `Style` as *implicit* style works perfectly if you target a distinct control like a `Button`. However, it *may* not work as you expect, if you target a **base type** of a control, like `FrameworkElement`, because each **derivative** of that base type can have their own style applied explicitly or implicitly that breaks your anticipated behavior by:

- Not being based on the style of the base type
- Not being based on a style that is transitively based on the base type style
- Overriding the properties of the base style

The essential misunderstanding here is that all styles of derivatives of a base type will base their style on the style of said base type, but this does not apply in general.

You can check this yourself by extracting the `Style` of any control via Visual Studio or Blend. For example, let's look at the `Style` of a `Button`. As you can see, it is not even based on `FrameworkElement`, so it will not apply your base style. Even if it would, there is a chance that it will override the `Margin` property itself.

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
   <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource PrimaryHueMidBrush}"/>
   <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource PrimaryHueMidBrush}"/>
   <!-- ...other setters. -->
</Style>
```

Apart from that, you have to define your base type style **before** any other styles of derivatives, because you can only use `BasedOn` with `StaticResource`. Consequently, if the style of a derived control is already defined before your style, your base style **will not be** applied.

Comment: [You can check this yourself by extracting the Style of any control via Visual Studio or Blend], Can you more specific about that.?

Comment: @dellos In VS designer, right click on a control then _Edit Style / Edit Template > Create a copy_. Then the **default style** for the control is extracted and you can see that this default style is not `BasedOn` the `FrameworkElement` style. Hence, your style is not applied.

Answer (score 0):

> What infomation am I missing here?

The fact that there are default styles defined for more derived types such as for example `Button` and `Control` and that these will take precedence over and be applied instead of your custom `FrameworkElement` style.

Your approach of defining a single `Style` for all `FrameworkElements` won't work. You'll need to define an implicit type for each derived `FrameworkElement` type.